# How to know whether SRV05-4 is working or not

Tags: diodes, esd, tvs, short-circuit

There are couple of SRV05-4 array of TVS diodes on our PCB. I want to know how can I tell whether one of them is working or not i.e. whether it's still alive or dead.

I was interfacing my board with other board and suddenly 2 pins which were connected to the SRV05-4 got short or are showing continuity earlier these pins were not showing continuity so I just wanted to know a method through which I could know whether the SRV05-4 is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the SRV05-4 and see if the problem goes away. Caution you have removed your protection. if the problem goes away then best to replace them with new parts. If the problem is still there it is further up the circuit. I am assuming you did you try using your meter in both directions.